# Bad pdf conversion using dvisvgm

Tags: dvisvgm

I'm trying to convert [this](https://gofile.io/d/VKoSqP) pdf file to svg file.

Using dvisvgm (2.9.1) with `dvisvgm --pdf testfile.pdf`, it gives me [this](https://gofile.io/d/eRSO6Y) ugly result. Using pdf2svg  (0.2.3) gives me [this](https://gofile.io/d/vI1bql) better result.

I tried some dvisvgm options, but I couldn't improve the result. Is there a way to get a result similar to pdf2vsg using dvisvgm ?

Comment: dvisvgm doesn't support PDF/PS shading patterns yet (in contrast to shading fills). So, unfortunately, there is currently no way to get a better result directly from this file.

Comment: Ok so the problem is solved. We must wait for a new version or continue working with pdf2svg.

Comment: @Martin -- Although I agree with closure, closed questions with no answers disappear.  Since the information why this is impossible is useful (although possibly temporary), an answer would be a good idea.  Please add one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the recent versions of dvisvgm can't convert the PDF file properly.

PDF and PostScript provide two different ways of creating color gradients: shading fills and shading patterns. dvisvgm only supports shading fills at the moment. Your PDF file, in contrast, uses 24 shading patterns as you can see in the following (shortened) output of `mutool`, for example:

```
$ mutool info testfile.pdf

PDF-1.4
Info object (2 0 R):
<</Producer(GPL Ghostscript 9.52)/CreationDate(D:20200519102225+02'00')/ModDate(D:20200519102225+02'00')/Creator(Asymptote 2.652.65)>>
Pages: 1

Retrieving info from pages 1-1...
Mediaboxes (1):
        1       (4 0 R):        [ 0 0 226.77 215.01 ]

Shading patterns (24):
        1       (4 0 R):        Tensor patch (54 0 R)
        ...

Patterns (24):
        1       (4 0 R):        Shading 54 0 R (55 0 R)
        ...
```

Since dvisvgm doesn't evaluate the shading patterns, the current fill color is used instead, which is black here.